# How do I make my OpenCart e-commerce site multilingual?

Tags: opencart

I am working in my first OpenCart website. How do I bring Dutch and English language into my site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenCart is built with a MVC+L (Model, View, and Controller + Language)... This makes it extremely easy to add and use language files...

In the admin/language and catalog/language directories you will find subdirectories with the related language files...

To create your own language pack, just translate all of the language files in the sub directories into your desired language (creating/naming the root /language directory accordingly...)

Once you have the translated files, you just need to insert the language into the DB_PREFIX / 'language' table in your database...

Full instructions are covered in the OpenCart forums:

*[How Do I Install or Create a New Language Pack?](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=2543)*